# Mapping a list inside another in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to map a list which has another list of objects but an error keep showing . Thank you for any help in advance

- My Class

```
 import 'Standing.dart';

class League {
    String? country;
    String? flag;
    int? id;
    String? logo;
    String? name;
    int? season;
    List<List<Standing>>? standings;

    League({this.country, this.flag, this.id, this.logo, this.name, this.season, this.standings});

    factory League.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return League(
            country: json['country'], 
            flag: json['flag'], 
            id: json['id'], 
            logo: json['logo'], 
            name: json['name'], 
            season: json['season'],
            standings: json['standings'] != null ? (json['standings'] as List).map((i) => List<Standing>.from(i)).toList() : [],
        );
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
        data['country'] = country;
        data['flag'] = flag;
        data['id'] = id;
        data['logo'] = logo;
        data['name'] = name;
        data['season'] = season;
        data['standings'] = standings?.map((v) => List<Standing>.from(v)).toList();
        return data;
    }
}
```

- Standings Class

```
 import 'All.dart';
import 'Away.dart';
import 'Home.dart';
import 'Team.dart';

class Standing {
    All? all;
    Away? away;
    String? form;
    int? goalsDiff;
    String? group;
    Home? home;
    int? points;
    int? rank;
    String? status;
    Team? team;
    String? update;

    Standing({this.all, this.away, this.form, this.goalsDiff, this.group, this.home, this.points, this.rank, this.status, this.team, this.update});

    factory Standing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Standing(
            all: json['all'] != null ? All.fromJson(json['all']) : null, 
            away: json['away'] != null ? Away.fromJson(json['away']) : null,
            form: json['form'], 
            goalsDiff: json['goalsDiff'], 
            group: json['group'], 
            home: json['home'] != null ? Home.fromJson(json['home']) : null, 
            points: json['points'], 
            rank: json['rank'], 
            status: json['status'], 
            team: json['team'] != null ? Team.fromJson(json['team']) : null, 
            update: json['update'], 
        );
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['form'] = this.form;
        data['goalsDiff'] = this.goalsDiff;
        data['group'] = this.group;
        data['points'] = this.points;
        data['rank'] = this.rank;
        data['status'] = this.status;
        data['update'] = this.update;
        final all = this.all;
        if (all != null) {
            data['all'] = all.toJson();
        }
        final away = this.away;
        if (away != null) {
            data['away'] = away.toJson();
        }

        final home = this.home;
        if (home != null) {
            data['home'] = home.toJson();
        }
        final team = this.team;
        if (team != null) {
            data['team'] = team.toJson();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

- data parsing

```
 Future<StModel?> getStandings(int leagueId , int season) async {
    HttpWithMiddleware httpClient = HttpWithMiddleware.build(middlewares: [
      HttpLogger(logLevel: LogLevel.BODY),
    ]);

    var fullUrl  = "${Utils.BASE_URL}standings?league=$leagueId&season=$season";
    var response = await httpClient.get(Uri.parse(fullUrl),headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-host' : Utils.HOST,
      'x-rapidapi-key' :  Utils.KEY,
    });

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var json  = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return StModel.fromJson(json);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

- Error
  [image]

Comment: You have syntax error in your expression. Also, `T` must be a type in `List<T>`. Not something dynamically computed during runtime like `Standing.fromJson(i)`. I think you are trying to do this `List<Standing>.from(i)`

Comment: Should be it like this then ? ....  standings: json['standings'] != null ? (json['standings'] as List).map((i) => List<Standing>.from(i)).toList()  : [],

Comment: I have updated the code if you do not mind taking a look at it

Comment: could you please include Standing class too?

Comment: @eamirho3ein Thank you for checking , i have included it as well

Comment: Could you please add one more thing? sample of your api response.

Comment: This is the whole response https://pastebin.pl/view/92f71ace

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
factory League.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return League(
        country: json['country'], 
        flag: json['flag'], 
        id: json['id'], 
        logo: json['logo'], 
        name: json['name'], 
        season: json['season'],
        standings: json['standings'] != null ? (json['standings'] as List).map((i) => List<Standing>.from(i)).toList() : [],
    );
}
```

to:

```
    factory League.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List<List<Standing>> _standings = [];
    for (var element in json['league']['standings'] as List) {
      List<Standing> temp = [];
      for (var item in element) {
        temp.add(Standing.fromJson(item));
      }
      _standings.add(temp);
    }
    return League(
      country: json['country'],
      flag: json['flag'],
      id: json['id'],
      logo: json['logo'],
      name: json['name'],
      season: json['season'],
      standings: _standings,
    );
  }
```

then use it like this:

```
if(response.statusCode == 200){
  var json  = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return League.fromJson(json['response']);
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry my bad, I updated my answer

Comment: check out the last Update @Taki

Comment: Yes i did actually copy paste the whole string and replaced it in my file and started the app , it showed that error

Comment: 2 min ago I added as List<Standing>. check it again please @Taki

Comment: could you please give it a try and check out last update.@Taki

Comment: the last image you added was not my last update

Comment: some how I could not able to pars that list with shorter version, please try my last update, I hope it fixes your issue. @Taki

Comment: Yes I think, but I add your response to a variable and able to parse it like last update.

Comment: Thank you again , but showing an error even though i feel like your code is good , here is the error generated https://ibb.co/B6FB13v

Comment: could you please include the part that you use your api response?

Comment: I have used httpmiddleware to check if the response is successful , and it is successful , cause i ve also tried different plugins to generate the class , they failed in that part as wel

Comment: please include code of that part you are using api response and try to pars it

Comment: I'm parsing it already and it is throwing an error like i showed earlier ,  it keeps saying that Tried calling [](('standings')

Comment: I have included the code for parsing my data , please check it out

Comment: what StModel is?

Comment: Thank you for the help , i actually found a website which provided me the correct syntax and it works fine now , if you want to take a look